# Installing MAMP on server and accessing remotely

Tags: php, mamp

I have installed MAMP on a server and placed my PHP files in the htdocs folder. Is it possible to access these files from a remote computer and run them just as if they were local? I've done some research but I can't quite figure it out. I'm aware this method isn't very secure too.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It depends on your network configuration, but typically involves forwarding the port on your router to your computer. Shouldn't take much more than that.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to elaborate a little more?

Comment: Not really, but there's [plenty](https://pixelfear.com/blog/sharing-a-local-dev-server-with-your-clients-using-mamp) of [resources](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/diy-hosting-using-no-ip-mamp/) to [utilize](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/mac-platform/articles/48622.aspx).

Comment: I'm still having issues but the links are definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having some issues with MAMP. I changed to XAMPP, changed to port, and everything has been working great!